# One of my phone's last location is in different continent

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, google-account, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

today, on my Google Account, I saw that one of the last locations of my phone is from the USA when I live in Europe? Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't been to the US recently and haven't used a VPN connection on your phone, this is not right. The first thing I would do in this case is to change your Google password.
Maybe go through the Google security checkup, some good advice on there: https://security.google.com